# Algebraic inequality using AM-GM

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Let $a, b, c > 0$. Prove that

$\frac{2}{3}\left(\frac{a^2}{b^2} + \frac{b^2}{c^2} + \frac{c^2}{a^2}\right) + abc \geq a + b + c.$

I used AM-GM and got

$\frac{a^2}{b^2} + \frac{b^2}{c^2} + \frac{c^2}{a^2} \geq 3$.

Thus, we have that

$2\left(\frac{a^2}{b^2} + \frac{b^2}{c^2} + \frac{c^2}{a^2}\right) + 3abc \geq \frac{a^2}{b^2} + \frac{b^2}{c^2} + \frac{c^2}{a^2} + 3 + 3abc$,

and we want to prove that

$\frac{a^2}{b^2} + \frac{b^2}{c^2} + \frac{c^2}{a^2} + 3 + 3abc \geq 3(a + b + c)$.

Then I noticed that

$\frac{a^2}{b^2} + abc + 1 \geq 3a\sqrt[3]{\frac{c}{b}}$

and the others. So, the inequality becomes

$a\sqrt[3]{\frac{c}{b}} + b\sqrt[3]{\frac{a}{c}} + c\sqrt[3]{\frac{b}{a}} \geq a + b + c$,

and I got stuck here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use AM-GM, consider finding non-negative reals $p, q, r, s$ s.t. $p+q+r+s=1$ and $$p\frac{a^2}{b^2}+q\frac{b^2}{c^2}+r\frac{c^2}{a^2}+s\cdot abc \geqslant a^{2p-2r+s}b^{2q-2p+s}c^{2r-2q+s}=a$$
Hence we get
$$p+q+r+s=1, \quad 2p-2r=1-s, \quad 2p-2q=2q-2r=s $$
$$\implies (p, q, r, s) = \left(\frac7{18}, \frac29, \frac1{18}, \frac13 \right)$$
and hence the AM-GM:
$$7\frac{a^2}{b^2}+4\frac{b^2}{c^2}+\frac{c^2}{a^2}+6abc \geqslant 18\sqrt[18]{\frac{a^{14}b^8c^2}{b^{14}c^8a^2}a^6b^6c^6}=18a$$
Cyclically summing that last AM-GM is equivalent to the inequality needed. Equality is when $a=b=c=1$.